# How to conditionally render in Flutter

Tags: flutter, conditional-statements, flutter-widget

I have a wallet circle which is responsive to the payments that are done. What my issue is when ever the wallet amount is zero, I want the widget that draws the circle to be non visible.

What I did now, is that I used a ternary operatior for checking it inside Custompaint Widget. What am I missing?.

```
 CustomPaint(
                    painter: (this.total <= 0)
                        ? CurvePainter(colors: [
                            // To test if the color changes
                            Colors.red.withOpacity(0.9),
                            Colors.red.withOpacity(0.9)
                          ], angle: 0, strokeWidth: 0)
                        : CurvePainter(
                            colors: [
                              Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                              Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                            ],
                            angle: 360 - ((this.used / this.total) * 360),
                            strokeWidth: this.strokeWidth,
                          ),
                    size: Size.fromRadius(strokeWidth),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: this.radius,
                      height: this.radius,
                    ),
                  

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to paint widget conditionally you can use ternary operator like this:

```
    (this.total <= 0)
       ? CustomPaint(
            painter:CurvePainter(
                    colors: [
                      Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                      Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                            ],
                    angle: 360 - ((this.used / this.total) * 360),
                    strokeWidth: this.strokeWidth,
                          ),
            size: Size.fromRadius(strokeWidth),
            child: SizedBox(
                      width: this.radius,
                      height: this.radius,
                    ),
        ) : Container(), // <--- Use it here, not inside CustomPainter
```

Comment: My objective is to draw Curvepainter which is the positional argument of Custompaint, according to the conditions. It should only effect Curvepainter.. When this.total gets zero the curvepainter shouldn't be drawn

Comment: When Container() with no arguments gets to the widget tree it affects nothing. On the other side when you pass to painter zero width it will still rendered, and in most cases painted with minimal width.

Comment: Other way is to pass condition value to painter class and create function which will execute depending on its state. Its more complicated but good solution when your painter consist of multiple paint functions and you want them to render separately.

Answer (score 0):

Do you change the variable inside setState?

```
setState((){
 total = 0;
});
```

setstate rerenders the screen.